# Creating an animated list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of text separated by `<br/>`, I would like to animate each of them using random shuffle after each click event, the post-top-position after each click is randomly determined.

```
<html>
<body>
  <span id="text1">Text1</span>
  <span id="text2">Text2</span>
  <span id="text3">Text3</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('body').on('click',function(e){
    $('span').eq((e.pageX+e.pageY)%3).appendTo($('#container_div'));
    })
```

where container_div is the id of the div that contains these spans....in this case you can just have 'body'

Well actually its not random but considering the user mouse clicks would be random it will give random results...

As you can see I take the sum of x and y position of mouse click and take the modulus by 3
and chose that span (modulus will be either 0,1 or 2) to move to the top of the list